# How can I take data from this input box?

Tags: python, django, web

I have a input type defined as:

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="{{ username}}" />
```

How can I take data from this input box? Are there a get method for taking those text from input box? I know this is simple question, but I am trying to learn them.

Comment: Do you want to get the value of the input field in view or in template?

Comment: @AamirAdnan it is declared in the template. I want to get its value in the code. After people wrote something in the text filed, I want to get those text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the `request.method`, in your view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username')
else:
    username = request.GET.get('username')
```

Comment: Do not use if else logic, i have mentioned it just for clarification. Use either `request.POST` or `request.GET` depending on your form method.

Comment: @m01 see my first comment :)

Comment: can I clear what the text data is in the text field over using django  after data entered by user is used by my function ?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that input element is in a form that a user will submit, you can catch the submitted value in your view function:

```
def submit(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        do_something_with(username)
```

see also the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/).

Comment: with the same way, can I set the value of the 'username' ?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you mean. You're outputting the value in a template, so you'll need to feed whatever updated value of `username` to that template. This is all covered in the [Django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/); I'd suggest to work through all of them to get to grips with all the basics.

Comment: After getting the text, I want to erase all data on the text field, sort of setting new value to it.

Comment: Please note that you can't 'control' the client side from the server side. What you're asking involves quite a bit more than you've shown us. Please work through the tutorials linked in the previous comment ;)

Comment: Why is it not possible ? After user writes him/her password to the text field, the field should be erased. But, you said it is not possible. Thanks for tutorial.